# ImageButton relative size and position

Tags: android

I am trying to scale an `ImageButton` to fit 50% of the screen width and center it horizontally, no matter what the original image or device screen sizes are. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3mN7.jpg) describes more accurately what is the final result I am looking for.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It would help to see some of your efforts/attempts at this implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve the effect you are looking for is to use the `weight` attribute of the children of a `LinearLayout` combined with 2 invisible `Views` that will act as 25% padding on either side. Seriously, though, your question could have been way better, please read the SO posting guidelines next time.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">


    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry for how the question was asked but it was late and I thought an image is worth a thousand words. Thank you very much, this is almost doing it. Two things: ImageButtons are not scaling the image correctly, so I used ImageViews, and I had to add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in order to remove the free space left after the scaling.